# Flagging cells on detecting change in data, after making an API call in Google Sheets using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

I am creating a project where I have to call a 3rd party API that provides different details regarding different hotels in a place and store the data in a Google Sheet. Among them, data fields that constantly change are :

- price of a room
- availability of a room
- tenancy length etc.

Based on this I have to perform the following tasks :

1. Create a trigger that automatically runs the data fetching function every day (this most probably can be done by creating functions for triggering elements)
2. Store the updated data in the respective sheet
3. Compare the new data with the existing data in the sheet
4. Flag the cells where the data has been changed (possibly by coloring the cell or row) e.g if one cell value in the **price** column has changed from 2 to 3, I color that cell green. Also, the next time I call the function again, the **color should go back to white** if no change has been detected again.
5. There will also be a column **change_timestamp** which will update the last change
6. Finally, send an email to a person saying that a value in the specific sheet and specific row has changed

I am adding code snippet which I used to fetch data from a particular hotel management group's API

```
const unitedss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const uniteSheet=unitedss.getSheetByName("Unite_API Test"); //there are multiple sheets in the same spreadsheet which I access individually through the given function
uniteSheet.activate();

const cities=["aberdeen","bath","bedford","birmingham","bournemouth","bristol","cardiff","Coventry","Durham","Exeter","Edinburgh","Glasgow","leeds","Leicester","london","liverpool","Loughborough","Manchester","Medway","Newcastle","Nottingham","Oxford","Portsmouth","Reading","Sheffield","Southampton","Wolverhampton"];

//the header row 
let uniteHeader=[["property","property_id","room","room_id","total_rooms","tenancy","tenancy_id","academic_year","check_in","min_check_in","max_check_in","check_out","min_check_out","max_check_out","duration","duration_unit","price","price_duration_unit","deposit","currency","availability","data_added_timestamp","change","change_timestamp","amber_url"]];
uniteSheet.appendRow(uniteHeader);

//function to add header
function addUniteHeader(){
  let range=uniteSheet.getRange(1,1,1,uniteHeader[0].length);
  range.setValues(uniteHeader);
  range.setFontWeight("bold");
  uniteSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
}


function getAllUniteData() {
  let range=uniteSheet.getRange(2,1,uniteSheet.getLastRow()-1,uniteHeader[0].length);
  range.clear();   //clears the previous data that existed in the sheet except the header row
  
  //create the matrix
  for(let city=0;city<cities.length;city++){
    let array=[]; //a 2-D array which will store all the data
    let reqCity=cities[city].toLowerCase();
    let data=JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://myApiEndPoint/cities/${reqCity}`).getContentText());
    let properties=data.PropertyData;   //[it is an array of objects]
    if(properties===undefined)continue;

    for (let prop=0;prop<properties.length;prop++){
      let propName=properties[prop].PropertyName;  //name of the property
      let propID=properties[prop].PropertySerial;  //id of the property
      let x=encodeURIComponent(propName);
      let propData=JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://myApiEndPoint/cities/${cities[city]}/properties/${x}`).getContentText());   //[returns an object]
    if(propData===undefined)continue;
      let roomInfo=propData.RoomData; //[an array of objects]
    if(roomInfo===undefined)continue;

    for(let r=0;r<roomInfo.length;r++){
        let typeGroup=roomInfo[r].TypeGroupName; //name of roomType to which this object pertains
        let details=roomInfo[r].RoomTypeAndClasses; //an array of objects 
    if(details===undefined)continue;
        for(let i=0;i<details.length;i++){

            let classOfRoom=details[i].RoomClassName;
            let roomType=details[i].RoomType; 
            let finalRoom=classOfRoom+" "+roomType; //the room type
            let roomID=createRoomID(propID,i+1);  //id of room
            let tenancies=details[i].TenancyTypes; //an array of tenancy objects applicable to this room type and class
            if(tenancies===undefined)continue;

            for(let ten=0;ten<tenancies.length;ten++){
                //tenancies[ten] is an object
                let tenancyName=tenancies[ten].Name;
                let tenancyID="";  
                let tenancyAvail=tenancies[ten].isSoldOut?"NO":"YES"; 
                let availBands=tenancies[ten].AvailabilityBands;  //an array of objects
                if(availBands===undefined)continue;

                for(let j=0;j<availBands.length;j++){

                    let availability=availBands[j]; //an object which gives availability details
                    let acadYr=availability.AcademicYear;
                    let min_check_in=(new Date((availability.StartBand.S)*24*60*60*1000)).toDateString();
                    let checkin=((new Date((availability.StartBand.D)*24*60*60*1000))).toDateString();  
                    let max_check_in=((new Date((availability.StartBand.E)*24*60*60*1000))).toDateString();
                    let min_check_out=((new Date((availability.EndBand.S)*24*60*60*1000))).toDateString();
                    let checkout=((new Date((availability.EndBand.D)*24*60*60*1000))).toDateString();
                    let max_checkout=((new Date((availability.EndBand.E)*24*60*60*1000))).toDateString();
                    let price=availability.PricePerWeek; 
                    let price_duration="week";
                    let deposit_amnt=0; 
                    let duration=availability.Weeks;     
                    let durationUnit="weeks";
                    let totalRooms=availability.TotalRooms; 
                    let dateAdded=new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB',{timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata'});

                    let dataRow=[propName,propID,finalRoom,roomID,totalRooms,tenancyName,tenancyID,acadYr,checkin,min_check_in,max_check_in,checkout,min_check_out,max_checkout,duration,durationUnit,price,price_duration,deposit_amnt,"Pounds",tenancyAvail,dateAdded,"NO","",""];
                    array.push(dataRow);
                    //in the above row fields like price, deposit_amnt, tenancyAvail change regularly 
                }
            }
        }
      }

    }
  if(array===undefined||array[0]===undefined)continue;
  uniteSheet.getRange(uniteSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array); //populate the sheet with values of the 2-D array
  }

}


//A trigger which can run the function everyday 
function setUpTrigger(){
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("getAllUniteData")
    .timeBased()
    .everyDays(1)
    .atHour(8)
    .inTimeZone('India/Kolkata')
    .create();
}


//deletes all the triggers
function deleteTrigger() {
  
    // Loop over all triggers and delete them
    var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    
    for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
    }
  }
```

The images of the first few rows of my sheet after calling the **getAllUnitedData** function have been given below :

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

(Note that all the columns of the header in the 3 images belong to the SAME row of the SAME sheet)

I want to call the **SetUpTrigger()** once after which it will automatically run the function getAllUnitedData() every day. Now, my main problem is executing steps **3-6** ie. comparing the new data with previous data, flag cells based on data change, and send email listing the changed cells.

I am new to Apps Script and slowly learning it. However, I cannot find a solution to this specific issue even after a lot of searching. Kindly help me with this. I'll be happy to provide any other details if needed.

Comment: On what task exactly are you searching for solution? You might post the code you wrote so far

Comment: @WaximCorp I have edited the question and added some more details. I have also added the code snippet which fetches the data from an API. I have been able to fetch and store all the data till now but not being able to understand how to execute steps 3-6. Hope this helps

Comment: I won't have enough time to do it, but you should find solution by having 2 sheets (for example: "main" and "upload"). When you import data, you put everything in the "upload" sheet, and then you start find and compare algorithm with "main" for each line, each cell. That way you can easily detect change, put it color, or send notification.

Comment: Can you edit your question down to a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? At the moment it seems like you are asking a lot of different things. Try to narrow it down to one single question, and open multiple questions if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for replying @WaximCorp. I will surely try the approach you mentioned.

Comment: Okay @iansedano. I am trying to reframe the question to make it more understandable. I guess there is too much in it which makes it difficult to narrow down the problems.